# Targeting an iframe

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP and I'm really confused about this.  I have a line that submits a variable to a new page, all works well there.  But I have tried every way I can think of to add a target= to it and can't seem to make it work.  I have been able to get it to target the iframe but when I do, it doesn't pass the variable.  How would I add that to this line?

```
'<a href="test.php?id=' .$control . '" >EDIT</a>';
```

Comment: Try: https://www.php.net/manual/en/getting-started.php

Comment: Thanks.  That's a good site, I've learned a lot from there in the last few weeks.  I just can't seem to figure out how to get the target included in this situation.  I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to build the string properly with the single and double quotes.

Comment: personally, I'd recommend using AJAX to pass the PHP variables to JS, then use JS to build the iframe, keep client-side client-side.

Comment: You already know how to output e.g : `echo "Hello World"` ? right ? regarding the single and duple quotes question : try these codes out `echo "'";` and `echo '"';` and `echo "\""` you need to [read about strings in PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) and play a little with them. `echo '<a href="test.php?id=' .$control . '" target="_blank">EDIT</a>';`

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  I built the string I posted based on a few different examples that did not work at first.  I read numerous articles about concatenation but I'm still trying to sort all that out.  There seem to be a few different ways to do it, starting with double quotes, starting with single quotes, the use of the backslash, etc.  I've only been working with PHP for a couple weeks, but I've been a programmer since the early 80's.  I've avoided html and most web based languages but I'll be retiring soon and just decided to pursue it for the learning experience.  Thanks!

Comment: I would like to mark Accountant's answer as the accepted one but I'm not seeing any way to do it.